# How to exit rpm install in case of an error

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I am looking for a way to exit rpm install if some condition is false. I have added a small script in the %pre section that exits install if my condition fails.

The problem I am facing is I see that the %pre scriptlet is executed, and rpm install does fail. Yet at the end of it I get these 2 lines which I don't want -- Installed ... followed by Complete!

```
Downloading Packages:
Running Transaction Test
Finished Transaction Test
Transaction Test Succeeded
Running Transaction
missing file zyWhg1. exiting install..
error: %pre(tyr-3.2.1.x86_64) scriptlet failed, exit status 255
error:   install: %pre scriptlet failed (2), skipping tyr-3.2.1

Installed: tyr-3.2.1.x86_64 0:3.2.1
Complete!
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need this just to make sure there is certain file in the filesystem, you can do simple

```
Requires: /path/to/expected/file
```

Otherwise you are indeed out of luck probably.

I could think of extremely ugly solution that would involve killing rpm from within scriptlet, but that is beyond evil :-)

Comment: If it is required at install-time, use RPMs built in support for this. The pre section is for exceptional cases.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use Verification Scripts? 
[Writing Verification Scripts](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora_Draft_Documentation/0.1/html/RPM_Guide/ch10s03.html)