# How to roll back RPM installation if %pre section of SPEC file script return false

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I'm a newby in RPM building. I have to build RPM which would install a package only if file /etc/i-am-a-requirement exists on target machine. So I wrote

```
%pre
if test -f "/etc/i-am-a-requirement"; then 
echo "I'm OK to continue"
else
echo "The file is not found, the RPM won't be installed"
-- How to add failure here? --
fi
```

I know that normally we expect RPM to have dependency packages, but in this case "/etc/i-am-a-requirement" is distributed as binary, so it does not have a package at all.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9932562/how-to-exit-rpm-install-in-case-of-an-error?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `%pre`, `%post` and other scripts cannot stop the installation of an rpm. Once you are inside the scriptlets; installation will continue nomatter the exit code of your scriptlets.

You should use **Requires:**

```
Requires: /etc/i-am-a-requirement
```

Comment: Does it work if `/etc/i-am-a-requirement` is not in an rpm package itself?

Comment: `%post` cannot, but `%pre` can - just call `false`. It won't "roll back" anything you did in the script tho. As for the `Requires` flag you answered with, that is the proper solution. I am unsure off-hand if it looks directly at the file system or checks the RPM DB.

Comment: Thanks @aaron for the clarification. wilqu: yes it works with just a file, but as Aaron said, unsure whether it will search for the file on-disk or just in the rpm db.